# Why does my shortcode wrap injected text with quotes?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

In my Wordpress site I'm building a plugin that injects a shortcode into a page. When I view the page it just shows the code of the shortcode:

```
[learndash_course_grid skin='grid' card='grid-2' thumbnail_size='large' post_meta='false' taxonomies='ld_course_tag:"Emergency Preparedness"']
```

When I view page source I see that the shortcode code is wrapped in double-quotes, so the page is just rendering it as a text string. If I put the shortcode into a page manually, it executes the shortcode correctly, so I know the shortcode itself is valid.

Is there a way to have that not happen, so the shortcode can actually execute?

Comment: How exactly are you 'injecting' the shortcode?

Comment: @Fewture Basically just like this:  

`
function my_custom_div($atts = [], $content = null, $tag = '') {  
  $args = shortcode_atts(array(  
                'title'        => 'sample title',    
  'tag'  => 'sample tag'  
                 ),$atts);  
  ?>  
<div >
 [learndash_course_grid values="a variety of things go here"]  
</div>  

<?php  
}  
?>`  

And the shortcode is called in the page like this:  

[my_custom_div title="This is my title(sure, remember it could have a graphic)" tag="Resources"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at the do_shortcode function.
You can find a documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/).

You can call the shortcode like this from your php code:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[learndash_course_grid skin="grid" card="grid-2" thumbnail_size="large" post_meta="false" taxonomies="ld_course_tag:'Emergency Preparedness'"]' );
```